# Ubuntu don't work. Problem with microcode

Tags: boot, dual-boot, kernel, initramfs, microcode

I was doing an Ubuntu update. After rebooting the Ubuntu pc it stopped working.  I was seeing this error

0.039443) (Firmuare Bug1: TSC DEADLINE disabled due to Errata: please updat

: microcode to version: 0x25 (or later) 0.1227321 DMAR: [Firmuare Bug]: No firmuare reserved region can cover this RMRR [0x0000000094800000-0x000000009fffffffl, contact BIOS vendor for fixes

0.9793791 Kernel panic- not syncing: UFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0) 0.9794241 CPU: PID: 1 Conn: suapper/8 Tainted: G

I 5.15.0-52-generic #58-Ubuntu

0.979469] Harduare name: TOSHIBA SATELLITE L50-B/Type2 - Board Product Mane1, BIOS 2.08 12/02/2014 0.9795121 Call Trace:

0.979526]

0.9795421 show_stack+0x52/8x5c

E 0.979564) dump_stack_lul+0x4a/8x63

E 0.979587) dump_stack+0x18/8x16 [ 0.9796061 panic+0x149/8x321

E 0.979626] mount_block_root+0x144/0x1dd

E 0.9796511 mount root+0x10c/0x11c

0.9796711 prepare_namespace+0x13f/0x191 E 0.979695) kernel_init_freeable+0x18c/0x1b5

E

0.97972117 rest_init 0x100/0x100 0.9797433 kernel_init 8x1b/0x150

8.975764) 7 rest_init 0x100/0x100

8.9797851 ret_from_fork+0x22/0x30

0.9798881 TASK

E

E 0.9798421 Kernel Offset: 0x24a00000 from exffffffff81000000 (relocation range: 0xffffffff80000000-0xfff 6.9798943-end Kernel panic - not syncing: UFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0) ]——

I tried to solve it with some commands found on the forums, but after some tests now I can't use nothing.( 5.x-generix, 4.x-generic or recovery mode).  I believe the 5.x-generic stopped working after I used commands on initramfs.  (if I remember correctly, after launching these instructions I received an error "failed for too many errors"). I had found some command to update microcode, but now I can no longer use the terminal. What should I do? Currently I can start Windows with the dual boot. can i do something from there? possibly what should i do to recover the files i had on ubuntu? can i possibly reinstall Ubuntu from Windows without lose my files?

Comment: I think you are mixing up kernel and version. For example a version would be Ubuntu 22.04 and a kernel would be 15.5

Comment: You do not uninstall an OS you just install over it.

Comment: Ok.how? Considering my problems?

Comment: No where in your question does it say the version of Ubuntu you tried to install. I recommend you look at these 2 documents and reinstall the Ubuntu OS. https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-verify-ubuntu#1-overview  https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#1-overview